# UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification not fired on date Change

Tags: ios

I'm setting a significant time change notification in my AppDelegate as `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeChange) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];`

The `timeChange` function is not called when I change the date manually on the phone, even after I bring the app to the foreground.

I also tried `- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application` method but that too doesn't get called.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: When you change the date manually, your app is in background mode. And can't receive notification. Try to test on simulator.

Comment: If Im not wrong, even if the date change happened when the app was in background, the notification will be delivered once it returns to foreground. Isn't this right ?

Comment: @Aneesh Yes, that is correct.  At least in this new decade. :-)  Is there a way to determine what caused the notification (e.g., midnight crossing vs. timezone change)?